# jQuery Push and Hold with mouseleave too

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to figure out the best way to make some push buttons that have the following functionality:

- push (in this case mousedown for instant firing) and hold down
- if you push down, then drag the mouse, while holding, it should remove the "hold" state
- same thing for mouseup, as long as the cursor is still inside the push button

I think I'm pretty much there, but was wondering if and JS wizards had any other ideas / optimization.

[LIVE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/r3tjs/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>button0</p>
        <a class="button">push</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>button1</p>
        <a class="button">push</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>button2</p>
        <a class="button">push</a>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
(function(){

$('ul').delegate('.button', 'mousedown', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this),
        index = el.index('.button');

    console.log('button' +index + ' -> mousedown');

    el.text('hold').addClass('hold');

    $(el).on('mouseleave', function() {

        $(this).text('push').removeClass('hold').unbind('mouseleave mouseup');

        console.log('button' +index + ' -> mouseleave');                

    });

    $(el).on('mouseup', function() {

        $(this).text('push').removeClass('hold').unbind('mouseup mouseleave');

        console.log('button' +index + ' -> mouseup');            

    }); 

});


})();​
```

Thanks.

Comment: The question was if there's a better way to achieve this functionality. Also, while building that demo, I kind of figured it out myself, but I wanted to post anyways to get other people's opinion.

The reason I want this functionality, is because I'll be firing a function on mousedown, and then a function for mouseup, but want to make sure somebody doesn't mouseout of the button while the mousedown is happening, IE: somebody clicks down, holds, and moves out of the button area...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly - but if all you need is when the mouse moves the **hold** state is left, then you could just do the same thing you did for `mouseup` also for `mousemove`:

```
$(el).on('mousemove', function() {
    $(this).text('push').removeClass('hold').unbind('mouseup mouseleave mousemove');

    console.log('button' +index + ' -> mousemove');            

});
```

but remember to unbind all the `mousemove` events.

PS: I edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasPaumgarten/r3tjs/1/

Comment: on a small side note: if you use `on()` to bind events you should use `off()` to unbind them.

Comment: This is pretty close, but I actaully still want people to be able to move the mouse around inside the button area, but remove "hold" state on either mouseup or mouseleave (button area).

Comment: understood. So you it works as you wanted it to. I just read our comment. The code itself is fine - especially given that it accomplishes what you need. The only thing you could think about is making the listener function the same since both times you do the same thing (other than the console log). Think about the [DRY](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/03/22/the-dont-repeat-yourself-principle-and-the-wormhole-anti-pattern/) anti-pattern. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasPaumgarten/r3tjs/4/).

Comment: Nice @Mathias. I think this was just the sort of optimization I was looking for. Good to learn. Thanks.